# can I do many functions in one Onclick

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rendering

my component was ok untill i tried to do some functions by Onclick,so I got Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
I faced this problem when I added

```
onClick={setProduct(e.product_id), () => { addProduct(e.product_id) }
```

and my full component is :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';


const Cola = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
    const [product_id, setProduct] = useState("")

    useEffect(() => {
        getProd();
    }, []);

    const getProd = () => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/customer/product/2`)
            .then((result) => {
                setProducts(result.data);
                return 
            })
    }
    const addProduct = () => {
        axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/customer/additem`, {product_id})
    }
    return (

        <div className="row bg-light">
            {products.map((e, i) => (
                <div class="card " style={{ width: "18rem", margin: "32px", marginLeft: "50px" }}>
                    <img src={`${e.img_url}`} class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
                    <div class="card-body bg-secondary" >
                        <h5 class="card-title " style={{ color: "white" }}>{e.name}</h5>
                        <h5 class="card-title " style={{ marginTop: "20px", color: "white" }}>{e.price} jd</h5>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" onClick={setProduct(e.product_id), () => { addProduct(e.product_id) }} >اضافة</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}

        </div>
    )
}

export default Cola
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the function directly. So it triggers a re-render.
Assign a function the onClick handler rather than calling it.

```
onClick={() => setProduct(e.product_id), () => { addProduct(e.product_id) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call directly setProduct directly.

```
onClick={() => setProduct(e.product_id), () => { addProduct(e.product_id) }
```

Another way, simple and easy to read.

```
const clickHandler = (e) => {
  setProduct(e.product_id);
  addProduct(e.product_id);
}

<a href="#" class="btn btn-success" onClick={clickHandler} >Something</a>
```